# update table and String or binary data would be truncated

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

```
   if object_id('tempdb..#NT')is not null drop table #NT

    DECLARE @name NVARCHAR(12) 
    SET @name = 'ELSETI\';

    CREATE TABLE #NT (role char(50) NOT NULL,
    userr_id int,
    rolee_id int,
    loginn_name char(50) NOT NULL,
    workk_name char(50) NOT NULL
    )

    insert into #NT
    SELECT @name+''+psss.login_name as role,ppp.user_id,ppp.role_id,psss.login_name,psss.work_name 
    FROM security_role_user ppp
    INNER JOIN _users psss ON psss.user_id = ppp.user_id where ppp.role_id='68'
```

when i try to update

```
UPDATE
   [_users]
SET
    [_users].login_name = Table_B.role
FROM
    [_users]
    INNER JOIN #NT AS Table_B
        ON [_users].user_id = Table_B.userr_id
WHERE
    Table_B.rolee_id='68'
```

i recieve: **Msg 8152, Level 16, State 14, Line 23
String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated.**

Comment: select * from #NT https://i.stack.imgur.com/hp0ko.jpg

Comment: Just make sure that [_users].login_name has at least the same same as Table_B.role

Comment: select user_id,login_name from _users https://i.stack.imgur.com/kgSoQ.jpg

Comment: Are you sure this is MySQL code? I've never seen `object_id` in that context

Comment: MYSQL??? Are you sure???

Comment: i use it in Microsoft SQL Server Managment Studio. i edit tags

Comment: it means you have a value in Table_B.role that exceeds what [_users].login_name can accept.

Comment: The error is pretty explicit, which part is causing you issues?